# Error on SQL JOIN on 2 nested COUNT and GROUPBY statements

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to combine 2 queries, one counting the users in each country and the other counting the users in each country using public phones and merging the columns together. However, I keep getting an error near the inner join code region. I am using HeidiSQL so that is the only error message I get. Each nested query runs perfectly on its own. Anyone knows what's wrong?

```
SELECT
   AllUsers.country, 
   AllUsers.TotalUsers, 
   PublicUsers.PublicPhoneUsers
FROM

   (SELECT 
      country, 
      count(country) As "TotalUsers" 
   FROM 
      userlist
   GROUP BY 
      country) AS "AllUsers"

INNER JOIN

   (SELECT 
      country, 
      count(country) As "PublicPhoneUsers"
   FROM 
      userlist 
   WHERE 
      phone_public = 1 
   GROUP BY 
      country) AS "PublicUsers"

ON
   AllUsers.country = PublicUsers.country;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?  I don't see anything wrong at first glance.

Comment: I am using HeidiSQL so all it returns is that the error is near the inner join code region. Not very helpful error messages sadly.

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around the aliases?  Is this required?  What happens if you remove them?  You mentioned that each subquery runs without error.  Can you run `(SELECT country, ... ) AS "AllUsers"` and let us know the result?

Comment: ahh removing them worked. I guess its a bad habit as sometimes I need the column headers to contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the double quotation marks from both your column and table aliases:

```
SELECT AllUsers.country, AllUsers.TotalUsers, PublicUsers.PublicPhoneUsers
FROM
(
    SELECT country, COUNT(country) As TotalUsers
    FROM userlist
    GROUP BY country
) AS AllUsers
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT country, COUNT(country) As PublicPhoneUsers
    FROM userlist 
    WHERE phone_public = 1 
    GROUP BY country
) AS PublicUsers
ON AllUsers.country = PublicUsers.country
```

Comment: actually I removed all the quotes, including the ones in the subquery

Comment: But you mentioned that the subqueries worked on their own.  Also, the join should have been unaffected by the aliased columns.  In any case, I removed all double quotations.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe its a quirk in my SQL implementation.